FFT derivatives N/2 term: $(uz + (1-u)z^*)(uz + (1-u)z^*)^* \stackrel{?}{=} |u|^2 + |1-u|^2$, $u \in \mathbb{C}$, $z = e^{icx}$, $x,c \in \mathbb{R}$
I'm tracing through Steven Johnson's notes on FFT-based derivatives, and I've hit a snag.
On p3 we see that we can derive an expression for the minimal mean-squared slope:
$$ \frac{1}{L} \int_0^L |y'(x)|^2 dx =  \big(\frac{2\pi}{L}\big)^2 \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|Y_k|^2 (k +m_kN)^2 $$
where $Y_k$ are Fourier coefficients, $k$ are the indices of said coefficients, $N$ is the number of samples in the discrete signal we're transforming, and $m_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is an integer that offsets $k$ by some multiple of $N$. I follow all this calculus. It's pretty neat. You'll love tracing it.
Then he addresses the special case of $k = \frac{N}{2}$, the "Nyquist term", where we can't cleanly solve for a best $m_k$. He characterizes the two cases, the "positive" case and "negative" case, where instead of
$$ Y_{N/2} e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x} $$
in the integral, you use:
$$ Y_{N/2} [ue^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x} + (1-u) e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x}] $$
where $u \in \mathbb{C}$, the idea being that when you sub in $x = nL/N$, you get $e^{\pm i \pi n}$, which matches the inverse discrete Fourier transform (IDFT).
The claim is that the contribution in the minimal mean-squared slope summation from this $\frac{N}{2}^{th}$ term is then
$$ \big(\frac{\pi N}{L}\big)^2 |Y_{N/2}|^2 [|u|^2 + |1-u|^2]$$
and you can then minimize w.r.t. $u$ to find the contribution of the "positive" and "negative" pieces should be exactly 1/2 each, which results in a nice little cosine in the important, boxed equation on the next line, because $cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$.
But! I can not figure out where that $|u|^2 + |1-u|^2$ comes from. If I let $z = e^{-i \frac{\pi N}{L} x}$, then when I plug the linear-combination version of $Y_{N/2}$ in to the sum, I get
$$ \big(\frac{2 \pi}{L}\big)^2 (Y_{N/2} [ue^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x} + (1-u) e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x}] \frac{N}{2})(Y_{N/2} [ue^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x} + (1-u) e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{L}(\frac{N}{2})x}] \frac{N}{2})^* $$
where $^*$ denotes a complex conjugate.
$$ = \big(\frac{\pi N}{L}\big)^2 |Y_{N/2}|^2 (uz + (1-u) z^*)(uz + (1-u)z^*)^* $$
which leaves me with
$$(uz + (1-u)z^*)(uz + (1-u)z^*)^* \stackrel{?}{=} |u|^2 + |1-u|^2$$
for $u \in \mathbb{C}$, $z = e^{icx}$, $x,c \in \mathbb{R}$
Every time I try to do the algebra, I end up with $|u|^2 + |1-u|^2 + crossterms$, and I can't understand how to get the cross terms to cancel. What am I missing?

I've figured it out. You have to go all the way back to the integral (a step I abbreviated out in the question) and plug in the expression for $Y_{N/2}$ there.
On p3 of Johnson, we see an expanded integral-and-sum. Instead of $ Y_k e^{\frac{2\pi i}{L}(k + m_kN)x} $ and $ Y_{k'} e^{\frac{2\pi i}{L}(k' + m_kN)x} $, use $_{/2}[^{\frac{2}{}(\frac{}{2})}+(1−)^{-\frac{2}{}(\frac{}{2})}] $ in the integral.
If you rearrange some things, you end up with a factor inside the sum of
$$ \int_0^L (Y_{N/2}[^{\frac{2}{}(\frac{}{2})}+(1−)^{-\frac{2}{}(\frac{}{2})}])(Y_{N/2}[^{\frac{2}{}(\frac{}{2})}+(1−)^{-\frac{2}{}(\frac{}{2})}])^* dx$$
$$ = |Y_{N/2}|^2 \int_0^L (uz + (1-u)z^*)(uz + (1-u)z^*)^* dx$$
Now the magic happens! We can expand that integral and use Fourier properties to get rid of the cross terms!
$$ uu^* \int_0^L zz^* dx \ + \ (1-u)(1-u)^* \int_0^L z^*z \ dx \ + \ u(1-u)^* \int_0^L z^2 dx \ + \ (1-u)u^* \int_0^L (z^*)^2 dx$$
Notice that $zz^*$ and $z^*z$ = 1! So those integrals end up equalling exactly $L$. But $z^2$ and $(z^*)^2$ are periodic, and we're integrating them over exactly $L$ periods, so those integrals end up 0!
Take what's left: The $L$ cancels a $\frac{1}{L}$ in the part of sum expression I didn't write here, and
$$ uu^* + (1-u)(1-u)^* = |u|^2 + |1-u|^2$$
